# Aliases for keywords

Tags: scheme

```
(define defun define)
```

It raises error `define: not allowed in an expression context in: define` in Racket. How to create aliases for  fundamental constructs like `define`, `let`, `lambda`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`define` is a syntax, not a first-class object. You cannot refer to it as an object.

As Justin said, you can create a macro. But note that Lisp-style `defun` has different syntax to Scheme-style `define`, and your macro should take that into account:

```
(define-syntax-rule (defun name params body ...)
  (define (name . params)
    body ...))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Racket specifically, but the more general problem is that in Scheme `define`, `let` and `lambda` are syntax and/or special forms rather than functions. So you cannot reference them in an expression context like you could if they were defined as functions.

But instead, you can define a macro `defun` that expands into a `define` expression.

Answer (score 1):

With normal procedures you can alias with define:

```
(define first car)  ; first isn't defined in R[67]RS
```

However `define` and `defun` isn't form compatible. This macro will make a global `defun` that works as in Common Lisp:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base))

(define-syntax defun
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((defun name args . body)
     (define (name . args) . body))))
```

`define` in Scheme has more hats than `defun`, mostly because of the one-namespace nature of Scheme. `define` works as `labels`, `flet`, `defconstant` and `setq` (but for previously bound, one need to use `set!` to update).